# Rails - Curb gem - Failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, memory-management, curb

During a running task this exception is raised by the Curb gem (https://github.com/taf2/curb).

```
failed to allocate memory
```

It's strange because before the Exception the gem works properly (with others curl calls).

Any ideas?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu server (and same error in dev mode locally - Mac OS X)

**EDIT**
In my task I do very much (+10k) calls like this

```
req = Curl::Easy.new do |curl| 
    curl.ssl_verify_peer = false
    curl.url = url
    curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
end
req.perform
```

Comment: How big is the file you are wanting to download?  Also... why is it that you are needing to call something like your code example 10,000+ times?  My guess is that your code is just using too much memory... :)  Is there any way to use less calls in your code?

Comment: @summea I don't think that is a problem of "weight" of the response, there are all pure-json-text (max 1k row of text ~ 30kb), and these are not stored: only read. Sadly I can't do less calls, every call is a request of a specific content

Comment: Hmm; even if your called content is small, the fact that you are creating a new Curl object 10,000+ times would lead me to think that this is part of what is causing your memory issues....  Is there any way to combine your calls?

Comment: @summea maybe re-using the Curl object for the others calls, but I don't know if works in this manner. In addition, in another task I use the same "Curl" procedure with no issues (even with "very much" calls).

Comment: @summea maybe if possible I can deallocate manually the memory of the object, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hmm, well, before that, it might be a good idea to "profile" your code so that you can have a better view at what is going on with the memory usage :)  There are probably other tools out there (and even a profiler included with Ruby itself...) but here is a nice profiler if you want to try it: http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/